# Use MKL to build .so and dyn.load in R

Tags: r, fortran, shared-libraries

I am stuck in making shared object with MKL and dyn.load it in R. 
The FORTRAN testing code is

```
SUBROUTINE invf_Rf(XX,iXX,n)
    implicit none
    double precision, dimension(:,:) ::  XX(n,n),iXX(n,n)
    integer n,INFO
    iXX=XX
    call DPOTRF( 'U',n , iXX,n,INFO)

    call DPOTRI( 'U',n , iXX,n,INFO)

end SUBROUTINE
```

And I use the MKL link advisor to complied it, the makevars file is:

```
PKG_LIBS= $(FLIBS)  -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_ilp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl  -fdefault-integer-8 -m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include -I/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64
```

when I load it in R and use it, the debug error is:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so.
[Inferior 1 (process 13619) exited with code 02]
```

Thanks for helping!!